# Inheritance of purity

Tags: dask

How does inheritance of function purity work? For example, I would expect for this code:

```
In [150]: myObj = delayed(dict,{}, pure=True)

In [151]: myObj
Out[151]: Delayed('dict-343cc4b6676839eb7fd74272cd0a1ed1')

In [152]: myObj = delayed(dict,{}, pure=True)

In [153]: myObj
Out[153]: Delayed('dict-343cc4b6676839eb7fd74272cd0a1ed1')

In [154]: myObj.foo
Out[154]: Delayed('getattr-e1ffa164-8c0e-40ac-9e84-2dc2ed334f93')

In [155]: myObj.foo
Out[155]: Delayed('getattr-c0b9af63-2145-498a-979b-cdfb8e6a30a9')

In [156]: delayed(getattr,pure=True)(myObj, 'foo')
Out[156]: Delayed('getattr-5f98e6d14b9694ba16542b61a770d0f0')

In [157]: delayed(getattr,pure=True)(myObj, 'foo')
Out[157]: Delayed('getattr-5f98e6d14b9694ba16542b61a770d0f0')
```

that lines `Out[154]` and `Out[155]` yield the same key, since it is accessing an attribute from a delayed instance declared pure. However, it is not, and the only way to enforce purity is to explicity declare it, as shown in lines `[156]` and `[157]`.

This leads me to a question about how purity is inherited. Are there general rules for this or is this left intentionally undefined?

thanks! :-)

EDIT : This question has moved over to [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2073). An update will be posted when resolved.

EDIT 2 : removed extraneous `pure=True` at end of [156] and [157]

Answer (score 2):

From the docstring:

```
pure : bool, optional
     Indicates whether calling the resulting ``Delayed`` object is a pure
     operation. If True, arguments to the call are hashed to produce
     deterministic keys. Default is False.
```

In the code above, you're effectively declaring a pure function `dict` (note that the `{}` passed in as `name` is a bad input, but works because it's false-y). Calling the resulting object results in the same key everytime, but the object itself isn't considered pure.

```
In [1]: from dask import delayed

In [2]: f = delayed(dict, pure=True)

In [3]: f(a=1, b=2)
Out[3]: Delayed('dict-33dc94312cd726f892eba4af7af52947')

In [4]: f(a=1, b=2)  # same key
Out[4]: Delayed('dict-33dc94312cd726f892eba4af7af52947')

In [5]: f.a
Out[5]: Delayed('getattr-e297bc1b-faef-4d0a-a2d6-99d1232065f1')

In [6]: f.a  # not the same key
Out[6]: Delayed('getattr-12bbbf19-fe91-4075-8992-2ebb63b391e9')
```

Methods on delayed objects can also be specified as pure with the `pure` keyword, but that of course won't work for attributes. This isn't something that was considered when originally writing the delayed interface.

```
In [7]: f.foo(a=1, pure=True)
Out[7]: Delayed('foo-b50c25f3e4249b9bd33a1e07975c9c27')

In [8]: f.foo(a=1, pure=True)  # same key
Out[8]: Delayed('foo-b50c25f3e4249b9bd33a1e07975c9c27')
```

I'd be open for changing how this works, and letting `delayed(object, pure=True)` indicate that all methods and attribute accesses are treated as pure. If you have a github account, could you [open an issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues) about this?